# WTForms Locale (Translating)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm building an APP using Flask, SQLAlchemy, WTForms 2.1 and WTForms-Alchemy (Python 2.7.10).
I'd like to change the locale of WTForms to translate the default messages (ex. "email already exists", etc). But when I set the "locales" on the Form class, I get the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No translation file found for domain: 'wtforms'
```

My form is:

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        locales = ('pt')

    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

The User model is:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usuario'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nome = db.Column(db.String(80), info={'label': u'Nome*:'}, nullable=False)
```

How can I set WTForms locale? I saw that they have many languages inside their locale folder.

Comment: Have you tried - locales = ['pt'] ?

Comment: This is the correct answer! I don't believe! Thank you a lot!